# Calculating array size in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, array, template

This code shows two ways to calculate size of array of any type. I would like to know, which should be preferred? Is there any advantage/disadvantage?

```
#include <iostream>

// First method
template<typename Arr>
std::size_t array_size_1(const Arr& arr)
{
  return sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
}
// Second method
template<typename T, std::size_t sz>
std::size_t array_size_2(const T (&arr)[sz])
{
  return sz;
}

int main() {
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  std::string sarr[] = {"abc", "def", "ghj"};
  std::cout << array_size_1(arr) << "\n";
  std::cout << array_size_2(sarr) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about [std::size()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)

Comment: @MartinYork That's unfortunately C++17.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yea. But it tells you how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both suffer (equal amounts) from the problem that when you call them, the compiler has to go instantiate a new function from the template. The code all ends up inlined after optimization, but it *does* make more work for the compiler than something like

```
#define NELEM(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof (x)[0])
```

The benefit of `array_size_2` is that if you try to call it as

```
int *p = nullptr;
std::vector<int> v;
size_t a = array_size_2(p);  // ERROR
size_t b = array_size_2(v);  // ERROR
```

the compiler will reject the call as ill-formed. Whereas if you do the same thing with `array_size_1` or `NELEM`, you'll just get for example `sizeof(int*) / sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(vector<int>) / sizeof(int)`, which isn't meaningful.

So `array_size_2` saves you from accidentally writing something meaningless. Especially in cases like

```
int foo(int a[]) {
    return array_size_1(a);  // OOPS!
}
```

where `int a[]` is just syntactic sugar for `int *a` and there's no actual array in existence at all.

Comment: #define-ing NELEM is not best practice in C++ (as tags states C++). `array_size_2` is a good way also to me.

Comment: @fiorentinoing - Can you please explain why NELEM is not a good practice in c++ ?

Comment: my reference is Scott Meyers, Effective C++, Item 2: prefer consts, enums, and inlines to #defines.